# What is the correct pronunciation of "AJAX"?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

I have wondered for a while about how I should pronounce "AJAX" (asynchronous JavaScript and XML). I usually say "I-acs", as in the Amsterdam football club, but should I say "a-jacs" (as it looks in English) or simply as the acronym "A-J-A-X"? Or does it not matter?

Comment: I think the traditional English pronunciation is the latter, and that's how I'd say it.

Comment: The "official" spelling is Ajax (like the popular transliteration of the name of the Greek hero Αἴας), not AJAX, per the term's inventor.

Comment: So, by popular vote so far, it seems to be "Id-ʒacs" (with ʒ being like plea<b>s</b>ure).

Comment: Not really, no: the first A is like in ABC - closer to the Canadian "eh" than to the pronoun "I". And the *J* consonant can't really be separated into two parts like that: it's the sound of the *j* in *jack* and the *dg* in *lodge*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The traditional pronunciation for the detergent brand (and I think also the Greek hero, contrary to FX_'s answer) is `/ˈejdʒæks/` (often written `/ˈeɪdʒæks/`), which can serve as guidance.

Comment: +1 as well ... but you'd normally use the digraph ʤ rather than separate d and ʒ characters. Which is probably why I so rarely use IPA -- it can get to be rather like typing Chinese, even when your font includes the appropriate glyphs.

Comment: @Stan I use IPA all the time and rarely use the diagraph ʤ rather than the separate d and ʒ characters unless I am needing to emphasize that it is an affricate.

Comment: The answer is correct but AJAX is an acronym, so detergent, greek, football whatever, those nouns have no relevance here.

Answer (score 37):

I believe the correct pronunciation is Ay-Jacks.

My answer is a tweaked version of the answer found [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/ajax/g/bldefajax.htm).

Comment: I always considered it a derivation of the name of the household cleaner.  Eye-acks is very much a Dutch pronunciation of the spelling.

Comment: I live in Holland, use both daily and pronounce the javascript one ai-jacks with the ai like in aide and the stress on the first syllable. Being Danish, I pronounce the detergent I-yacks possibly out of old habit.

Comment: @JamesWood, is my answer what you are looking for? If so, would you be able to "Accept" it by clicking the check mark to the left of my answer since this is my first answer on this SE site and it would give me a few achievements.

Comment: It should be `Ay-Jacks` to be more precise.

Comment: @Synetechinc. there you go... Just to make you happy! I'm not a pronunciation spelling guru, so when I typed it like A-Jacks, I was inferring that you would pronounce the "A" like you say the letter. What you said makes sense, which is why I changed it.

Comment: I suppose to make it clear that the ‘a’ is pronounced like the letter, you could put it in single quotes. Most people don’t know IPA very well if at all so when I explain a pronunciation, I usually just list some words in which the sound occurs and capitalize that part. In this case I would probably write something like    “d **AY**  **J** ump  **A** pple  **KS** ” (trying to get the markdown to work)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked up on this discussion for a while (since February!). I will accept this as the final answer, having good support and ease of pronunciation (unlike the "iedzhacs" one). The reason why I first thought that it should be "ayax" is because I have a bit of a tendency to pronounce 'j's as they are in Dutch when I see an unfamiliar word. I barely know any Dutch ("voor", an I also happen to have picked up "bijectie" somehow), I just like the way that 'j' combines with 'i' to make English vowel 'y' (not in "bijectie", but it is in "Martijn" and the old spelling "Fijenoord").

Comment: Unless you are from Spanish-speaking world were it's ah-ah, or Slavic or German-speaking world where it's eye-uhks.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional pronunciation for the Greek hero is `ˈeɪdʒaks`, which can serve as guidance.

Comment: as msh210 notes below, you probably mean æ not a, for the a sound as in “jacks”

Comment: The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has what I pasted for Ajax, and |dʒak| for jack. It appears they don't employ strict IPA notation, then.

Comment: @F'x: Oxford's notation of /a/ is still IPA: it's meant to reflect pronunciation changes that have occurred for many British English speakers since the symbol /æ/ was standardized as representing the vowel phoneme in the word "trap." A list of the main differences between Oxford's scheme (devised by Clive Upton) and the older scheme used by e.g. Gimson is outlined in the following webpage by John Wells: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-english.htm

Answer (score 3):

The pronunciation I find on the NOAD is /ˈeɪˌdʒæks/, which matches as a friend of mine (who is American) pronounces the word, independently from the meaning of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Both `eɪdʒaks` and `aɪ.əs` are right because AJAX is referred to the mythological Greek hero.
I prefer to say `aɪ.əs` because is more similiar to the latin word `Aiax` and to the italian word `Aiace`.

Answer (score 0):

"A" like in "way" and "asynchronous."
"JAX" like "jacks" or "Jack's."
This comes from my experience as a programmer and a computer science student. Since it's an acronym and it's not very common in speech, multiple pronunciations could be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The Longman Pronunciation Dictionary suggests ['eɪdʒ æks] or ['aɪ æks].